# MATLAB Edit-field isn't accepting value for printing

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, handle

An error is showing while I am trying to assign ...

```
app.WBCCount = app.WBC_Count;
```

The error is ...

**Error setting property 'WBCCount' of class 'zia':
Cannot convert double value 76 to a handle**

A function will be invoked when I press a button named "countWBCButton". Here is the function where the error is occurring...

```
% Button pushed function: CountWBCButton
    function CountWBCButtonPushed(app, event)

        if app.c ==1
            app.WBCCount = app.WBC_Count;  %Error Error Error Error.....
        else
            msgbox('First segment WBC','Error' , 'error');
        end
    end
```

Error is showing at the error marked commented line in the above function

**WBCCount**

[image: WBCCount is a public property. It's properties are given in below picture..]

Comment: Can you strip down you GUI to the bare minimal, able to reproduce this issue? Without knowing what `app.WBC_Count` and how you set the `app.WBCCount` property it's gonna be hard to answer. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @rinkert WBC_Count is a private property in my Matlab application. It is only assigned once in the entire project that is app.WBC_Count = cc.NumObjects;

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58463305/edit) your question, and add the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce your error.

Comment: @rinkert I have edited a little. See, it may help you to understand .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory: `WBCCount` is a **handle** and `app.WBC_Count` is a **double**.

You are trying to place the value of a double directly to `WBCCount`, instead of setting the relevant property of `WBCCount`.

In case `app.WBCCount` is of class `matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField` use:

```
app.WBCCount.Value = app.WBC_Count;
```

Comment: After uptating your question, I can see class is `matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField`, so use: `app.WBCCount.Value = app.WBC_Count;`

Comment: My project contains thousand lines of code. So it's a bit difficult issue for me. Though I am ready to provide any info whoever will want.

Comment: app.WBCCount.Value = app.WBC_Count wokred. Thank you :)